Semigroup property in SPDEs
In fact, we know that a bounded linear operators on a Banach space $X$ satisfies the semigroup property, i.e. $$S(t+s)=S(t)S(s), \text{for every}\ t,s\geq 0.$$
However, in various literatures, I observed that there exists different rules with respect to the spatial variable in SPDEs when they used semigroup property. The first one is that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}G(t-r,x-y)G(s-r,z-y)dy=G(t+s-2r,x-z).$$
And the second one is that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}G(t-r,x-y)G(s-r,y-z)dy=G(t+s-2r,x-z).$$
I don't understand its rules especially for the spatial variable. Indeed, I use the semigroup property as long as eliminates the integral variable whatever adds or subtracts. But I don't know if it makes sense.
Note. I apologize beforehand if this question is trivial or my reasoning is naive.
